# How to ignore optional xsd attribute and list tag in spring boot

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, xsd

I have a xsd as follows (cannot change the xsd):

```
<xsd:element name="root">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="element1"/>
            <xsd:element ref="element2" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element ref="element3"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="lang" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="element2">       
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="childElement1"/>
            <xsd:element ref="childElement2"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="lang" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="element1">       
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:attribute name="lang" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="element3">       
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:attribute name="lang" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

... and so on..
From which the generated class is as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Element1")
public class Element1{

@XmlValue
protected String value;
@XmlAttribute(name = "lang")
protected String lang;
}
```

and the rest of the classes are similar.

And the final xml looks something like:

```
<root>
<Element1>
    <value>1</value>
    <lang/>
</Element1>
<Element2>
    <Element2>
        <ChildElement1>
            <value>2a</value>
                <lang/>
        </ChildElement1>
        <ChildElement2>
                <value>2b</value>
                <lang/>
        </ChildElement2>
    </Element2>
</Element2> 
<Element3>
    <value>3</value>
    <lang>Eng</lang>
</Element3>
<lang/>
```

However, I would like to have the following instead:

1. The lang tags(optional xml attribute) should not be there in the xml when they have no value. Also when they have value, they should be within the parent tag.And the value should also populate within parent element tags instead of a independent value tag.
2. The list of element2 when having just having 1 element, there should not be 2  tags.

   Something like this:

   ```
   <root>
   <Element1>1</Element1>  
       <Element2>
           <ChildElement1>2a</ChildElement1>
           <ChildElement2>2b</ChildElement2>
       </Element2>
   <Element3 lang="Eng">3</Element3>
   ```

   Any way to achive this?

This is basically the response of a rest operation. I am using spring boot, so I am not explicitly using JaxB marshalling and unmarshalling.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I have jackson-xml-formatter dependency in my pom (along with woodstox).

Lastly, sorry about the long post with lot of code snippets. Did not know how else to describe my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a self sufficient file to achieve this. Basically have a root with all elements. I just wrote it quickly to give you an idea. You can change the method name, class names as per your requirement.

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Element1")
public class Element1 {

    @XmlValue
    protected String value;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "lang")
    protected String lang;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getLang() {
        return lang;
    }

    public void setLang(String lang) {
        this.lang = lang;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Root r = new Root();
        Element1 e1 = new Element1();
        e1.setValue("1");
        Element2 e2 = new Element2();
        Element1 ce1 = new Element1();
        ce1.setValue("2a");
        e2.setChildElement1(ce1);
        Element1 ce2 = new Element1();
        ce2.setValue("2b");
        e2.setChildElement2(ce2);
        r.setElement2(e2);
        r.setElement(e1);
        Element1 e3 = new Element1();
        e3.setValue("3");
        e3.setLang("eng");
        r.setElement3(e3);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
        Marshaller marrshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marrshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

        marrshaller.marshal(r, System.out);
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Root {

    @XmlElement(name = "Element1")
    Element1 element;

    @XmlElement(name = "Element2")
    protected Element2 element2;

    public Element2 getElement2() {
        return element2;
    }

    public void setElement2(Element2 element2) {
        this.element2 = element2;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Element3")
    Element1 element3;

    public Element1 getElement3() {
        return element3;
    }

    public void setElement3(Element1 element3) {
        this.element3 = element3;
    }

    public Element1 getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public void setElement(Element1 element) {
        this.element = element;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "Element2")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Element2 {

    public Element1 getChildElement1() {
        return childElement1;
    }

    public void setChildElement1(Element1 childElement1) {
        this.childElement1 = childElement1;
    }

    public Element1 getChildElement2() {
        return childElement2;
    }

    public void setChildElement2(Element1 childElement2) {
        this.childElement2 = childElement2;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "ChildElement1")
    Element1 childElement1;

    @XmlElement(name = "ChildElement2")
    Element1 childElement2;
}
```

Comment: Sorry accidentally added this into your answer instead of the question. Any workaround you would suggest now?